# How to customize the OAuth2 login redirection endpoint base uri with Spring Security Webflux

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

Spring security in the servlet stack ( web ) allows you to customize the OAuth2 login redirection endpoint base uri in the Oauth2 authorization code grant flow as [given here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2login-advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-redirection-endpoint). I am trying to do the same for the reactive stack with Spring webflux. [The github issue here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5598) mentions an authorizationRequestResolver and authenticationMatcher on the Oauth2LoginSpec that can be used to customize the base uri but I am unable to figure out how. Can someone please help me out with the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

In WebFlux applications you can use the `authenticationMatcher()`.

```java
http
    .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
    )
    .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
        .authenticationMatcher(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"))
    );
```